# @mssql_query on cake php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, cakephp

I have to fire sql on loop .Problem is that , whenever sql fails inside loop , entire other sql of preceding loop will fail. for example i have loop with 100 iteration, let say on 10th iteration i got sql error , in that case it will not fire sql for remaining 90 iteration too.

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {

    $sql="BULK
                            INSERT epds_temp
                            FROM '{$uploadsCsv}1.csv'
                            WITH
                            (
                            FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
                            ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
                            )";
                        $this->Epd->query($sql);    



}
```

for  normal php i could have do `@mysql_query($sql);`

any ideas?

Comment: Please always mention the exact CakePHP version you are using!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for($i=0;$i<$n;$i++) {

    $sql="BULK INSERT epds_temp
            FROM '{$uploadsCsv}1.csv'
            WITH
            (
              FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
              ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
            )";

        try {
           $this->Epd->query($sql);    
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            continue;
        }
}
```